# Equivalent from C# matchObject.Value in Python?

Tags: c#, python, regex

I am trying to parse some C# code to Python. There are several regular expression in that code. Everything worked fine so far, but now I've got the following problem:

C# Code:

```
Match m = regEx.Match( Expression );
while( m.Success )
{
    Expression = Expression.Replace( m.Value, m.Groups[1].Value + this.Solve( m.Groups[2].Value ) );
}
```

What can I do to make this code working in python? I've already tried something like this:

```
matchObj = re.search(pattern = p, string = expression, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
while matchObj:
    if len(matchObj.group(3)) > 0:
        expression = re.sub(pattern = p, repl = matchObj.group(1) + self.solve(matchObj.group(2)), string = matchObj.string, flags = re.IGNORECASE) #Here is the problem...
```

So actually I am looking for something equivalent of matchObject.Value.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do; `match.group()` (without a parameter) returns the match the whole regex matches:

```
m = re.search( pattern, text )
if m and len( m.group(3) ) > 3:
    text = text.replace( m.group(), m.group(1) + solve( m.group(2) ) )
```

I’m not sure why you had a loop there, so I removed it. Another way, without using `str.replace` would be to manipulate the string based on the positions returned by `m.start()` and `m.end()`.

Comment: That was it. After debugging the C# code and the Python code I could find it out myself. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, re.search returns a Match object in python. From the docs:

> Scan through string looking for a location where this regular expression produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

To get the entire matched string from a python MatchObject, use the `group` method. `matchObj.group()` or `matchObj.group(0)` will return the entire matched string, while `matchObj.group(1)` will return the first matched group, etc. This works very similarly to C#'s Match.

Now, about your C# code... Isn't that an infinite while loop in there? `m.Success` will always return `true` and `m.Value` will always give you the same result. The `Match` method only matches the first occurrence of the regex. Are you perhaps wanting to use the `Matches` method, which returns a `MatchCollection`? Or does the `Solve` method you call in the replace actually update the value of `m`?